# merge pdf files by string in filename using ubuntu terminal

Tags: pdf, merge, terminal, ubuntu-16.04, pdftk

I have a large number of pdfs that need to be merged into files of 2-3 pages according to their titles.

For example if I had the following files;

```
jim_contract1.pdf
jim_contract2.pdf
jim_contract3.pdf
susie_contract1.pdf
susie_contract2.pdf
charlescontract1.pdf
charlescontract2.pdf
charlescontract3.pdf
charlescontract4.pdf
```

I want to be able to write a line of code for each group to merge the files to have the result

```
jim_contract_merged.pdf
susie_contract_merged.pdf
charlescontract_merged.pdf
```

I tried to use this code:

```
pdftk 'find -type f -name 'jim_contract*'' cat output jim_contract_merged.pdf
```

But it only returns an error message.

Is there a way to do this from the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
pdfunite 1.pdf 2.pdf n.pdf out.pdf
```

So in your case you could try

```
pdfunite jim_contract*.pdf jim_contract_merged.pdf
```

Or if you don't have the pfdunite command, try ghostscript:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=jim_contract_merged.pdf jim_contract*.pdf
```